# Dovecot install error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code

Tags: debian, installation, dovecot, debian-wheezy, dpkg

I am trying to install a mail server on my Raspberry Pi.

I have setup the FQDN and run `apt-get update`, and am trying to install postfix, mysql and dovecot with the command `apt-get install postfix postfix-mysql dovecot-core dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d dovecot-lmtpd dovecot-mysql mysql-server`

However, I get the error message:

```
Processing triggers for menu ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dovecot-imapd
 dovecot-lmtpd
 dovecot-pop3d
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried using `-f` when running the install command, and have also verified that the hostname is correct.

The full output of the install command can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mcbxiwdjclagd4x/installOutput.txt?dl=0) (with HOSTNAME being my actual hostname, and the same for DOMAIN and TLD).

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

The Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian Wheezy 05-05-2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's look like for me that you have IPv6 disabled on the host.

```
Restarting IMAP/POP3 mail server: dovecotError: socket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol
Error: service(imap-login): listen(::, 143) failed: Address family not supported by protocol
Error: socket() failed: Address family not supported by protocol
Error: service(imap-login): listen(::, 993) failed: Address family not supported by protocol
Fatal: Failed to start listeners
 failed!
```

I'm not familiar with Debian/Raspbian but those errors occurs when `dovecot` try to use network protocols (::) that are not supported by system. Are you sure Raspbian is fully IPv6-aware?